# Unmounting partiton on shutdown shows failure

Tags: mount, shutdown, fstab

I have the following in `/etc/fstab`:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   discard,errors=remount-ro       0 1

UUID=8ff508b8-3975-4ef9-acc1-8ea7aeec56dc      /home           ext4    defaults        0      2 
UUID=c95405a4-4f6e-4d7c-9c23-fad75ce0ec04      /home/mail      ext4    defaults        0      2
```

/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0

Whenever I reboot the server, it reports a failure to unmount `/home` (but reboots OK). I see syslog says:

```
Mar 03 08:55:31 systemd[1]: home-mail.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 03 08:55:31 systemd[1]: Unmounted /home/mail.
Mar 03 08:55:31 systemd[1]: Unmounting /home...
Mar 03 08:55:31 systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c95405a4\x2d4f6e\x2d4d7c\x2d9c23\x2dfad75ce0ec04.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 03 08:55:31 umount[3462067]: umount: /home: target is busy.
Mar 03 08:55:31 systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/c95405a4-4f6e-4d7c-9c23-fad75ce0ec04.
Mar 03 08:55:31 systemd[1]: home.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Mar 03 08:55:31 systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /home.
Mar 03 08:55:31 systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8ff508b8\x2d3975\x2d4ef9\x2dacc1\x2d8ea7aeec56dc.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 03 08:55:31 systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/8ff508b8-3975-4ef9-acc1-8ea7aeec56dc.
```

I'm not sure how to interpret what's going on there (seems to be doing things in parallel?) Reading man fstab doesn't seem to offer any clues. Is it to do with the nested mount `/home/mail` and/or something accessing the partition while the system is trying to unmount it (eg dovecot)? If so, how can I ensure that everything has finished using it before it's shut down? Mind you, I see no errors about `/home/mail` being busy.

`lsblk`

```
xvda    202:0    0    55G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0    55G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0    20T  0 disk 
├─xvdb1 202:17   0     5T  0 part /home
└─xvdb2 202:18   0    15T  0 part /home/mail
xvdd    202:48   0     5G  1 disk 
└─xvdd1 202:49   0     5G  1 part
```

Comment: I can't find any docs on unmounting order, nor options that influence it. I'd presume what happens is that unmounting might be done in the same order as mounting. So `/home` gets unmounted while `/home/mail` is still mounted, which results in it returning EBUSY. You can check your system logs btw to see if it's true. [systemd.mount docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.mount.html) mention an option `LazyUnmount` that might be useful in this case, although I'm not sure if it's possible to apply without converting `fstab` to a `.mount` configuration unit.

Comment: I suppose if something was accessing `/home/mail` you'd expect the message to be about that. So maybe the error is just the system going to unmount `/home`, finding it busy (because '/home/mail' is mounted on it) and so unmounts `/home/mail` before cleanly unmounting `/home`? Just a guess though. I note there's no `fsck` check or warning on the reboot, for example.

Comment: Okay, judging by logs you posted the order okay. So something indeed has opened a file in `/home` while system is shutting down. I think you need to debug what process could that be, so e.g. trying to make systemd to put you into an emergency mode at that point of shutting down *(Idk offhand how to do that)*, or maybe trying to shut down services/targets yourself in the order systemd would do it and then umount the file systems and see if it fails and why.

Comment: A similar `Failed unmounting /var` is normal, so I assume `Failed unmounting /home` is harmless. Unless it starts unusual `fsck`s at boot or shows a risk of data less, you can ignore it